# XmlWriter formatting issue

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

Hi i'm not overly familiar with the usage of XmlWriter so please bear with me. I have this piece of code below to format the StartElement of a piece of XML

```
 var soapEnv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
 using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
            {

                // Build Xml with xw.
                writer.WriteStartDocument();

                writer.WriteStartElement("soapenv", "Envelope", soapEnv);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "test", null, "testString");
```

This format returns:
 `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="testString">`

However I would like it to swap the 2 AttributeStrings aroung in the StartElement so it looks like this:

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:test="testString" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`

I am unsure of how to go about this. Could someone advise, I would be grateful.

Comment: Surely the order is not important? Both attributes are applied to the soapenv:Envelope object regardless. There's no order precedence involved here. I'm curious why you need the ordering of the attributes to be rigidly defined in this manner.

Comment: To ne honest the order of namespace declarations has no significance whatsoever. Do you have some technical reason why you need them in different order or is it a question of readability or aesthetics?

Comment: Yea I was aware that there is no order precedence here. xjuice hit the nail on the head its more about readability and consistency of XML between my code and another persons really. Just wanted to see was there an easy way of achieving it that's all.

Comment: Consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds - Ralph Waldo Emerson